# Javascript get URL parameter that starts with a specific string

Tags: javascript, url-parameters, startswith

With javascript, I'd like to return any url parameter(s) that start with **Loc-** as an array. Is there a regex that would return this, or an option to get all url parameters, then loop through the results?

Example: www.domain.com/?Loc-chicago=test

If two are present in the url, I need to get both, such as:

www.domain.com/?Loc-chicago=test&Loc-seattle=test2

Comment: There are lots of questions that answer how to get query string parameters in Javascript. I can't find any that are for getting all parameters as an array, but it should be pretty easy to derive that from the codes in those answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.location.search` to get all parameters after (and including `?`) from url. Then it's just a matter of looping through each parameter to check if it match.

Not sure what kind of array you expect for result but here is very rough and basic example to output only matched values in array:

```
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var qsvars = query.split("&");
var matched = qsvars.filter(function(qsvar){return qsvar.substring(0,4) === 'Loc-'});
matched.map(function(match){ return match.split("=")[1]})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`URLSearchparams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

> The `URLSearchParams` interface defines utility methods to work with the
>   query string of a URL.

```js
var url = new URL("http://" + "www.domain.com/?Loc-chicago=test&NotLoc=test1&Loc-seattle=test2");
var paramsString = url.search;

var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

for (var key of searchParams.keys()) {
  if (key.startsWith("Loc-")) {
    console.log(key, searchParams.get(key));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you can use that accepts a parameter for what you are looking for the parameter to start with:

```
function getUrlParameters(var matchVal) {
    var vars = [];
    var qstring = window.location.search;

    if (qstring) {
        var items = qstring.slice(1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var parmset = items[i].split('=');
            if(parmset[0].startsWith(matchVal)
                vars[parmset[0]] = parmset[1];
        }
    }
    return vars;
}
```